# How to get bundle for a subclass that is implementing a protocol in Swift 2?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift2

How to get the bundle for a class that implements a protocol? Here i'm trying with self.dynamicType

Say i have a list of possible colors which is stored in my repo as a keyvalue list, how do i access that when running the protocol in a XCTest ( where NSBundle.mainBundle() does not work)?

```
protocol Car {
    func possibleColors() -> [String]
}

extension Car {
     func possibleColors() -> [String]{
         let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
         if let path = bundle.pathForResource(unitName, ofType: "colors") {
             let keyValueList = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
                  return keyValueList.allKeys() as! [String]   
             }
         }
         return [String]()
    }
}
```

This line does not work:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
```

A valid approach to this is getting the bundle, if that can be done without getting the class, thats an ok answer. Just can't find a way as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
extension Car {
    func possibleColors() -> [String] {
        if let selfClass = self.dynamicType as? AnyClass {
            let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: selfClass)
            if let path = bundle.pathForResource("test", ofType: "colors") {
                if let keyValueList = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
                    return keyValueList.allKeys as! [String]
                }
            }
        }

        return [String]()
    }
}
```